# Google Docs Viewer does not show .xlsx file

Tags: jquery, google-docs, embedded-resource

I'm using Google Docs Viewer that is embedded in iFrame.

It's showing .xls, .xml, .csv files fine, but when trying to view .xlsx file it fails (as shown in screenshot)[image: Not showing data]

I specify two links for testing:

http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F______.__%2Fuploads%2FBook1.xlsx&embedded=true

http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://justinas.tk/uploads/Book1.xlsx&embedded=true

iFrames are appended using this jQuery

```
preview.append('<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://______.__/uploads/Book1.xlsx') + '&embedded=true"></iframe>');
preview.append('<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + 'http://______.__/uploads/Book1.xlsx' + '&embedded=true"></iframe>');
```

As specified [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423485?hl=en) Google Docs Viewer support .xlsx files.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some tests with mime-type of word documents .docx

File saved with King Soft: `ks.docx`
File saved with LibreOffice: `xj.docx`
File saved with MS Word: `word1.docx`

**`word1.docx:`**`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary`
**`ks.docx:`**`application/zip; charset=binary`
**`xj.docx:`**`application/zip; charset=binary`

PHP script to get these results:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo 'word1.docx: ' . finfo_file($finfo, 'word1.docx') . '<br/>';
echo 'ks.docx: ' . finfo_file($finfo, 'ks.docx') . '<br/>';
echo 'xj.docx: ' . finfo_file($finfo, 'xj.docx');
```

As you can see it's mime-type that is wrong from other non-ms-word programs.

Comment: so you want to say if i generate a csv from ubuntu OS it wont work?